# Loading image vs full page post back?

Tags: ajax

If I have a large table of data that when sorted take like 5-10 secs to sort, is it a better UX to just do a page post back or better to add a loading image and use ajax call?

Comment: You generally get better answers if you show what prior research you have done and what your use-case is as different contexts would result in different answers.  I.E. if your users are customers on an e-commerce site versus business analysts using a reporting interface 5-10 seconds can mean a world of difference.  As it stands now your question is incredibly broad and unqualified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If time is actually around 5 seconds, having a circular (uncontrolled) gif would do but if the time is around 10 seconds, then you need a loading bar which show how much is done and how much is left.

BUT

Such a delay is poor UX as ajax has changed user's expectations and even when there is large data to load, user expects he would be shown some data straight-away and more will keep loading while he makes use of loaded one. So if it possible, provide loading in segments and don't make your user wait at all.

Comment: Ah, I see so paging may be a better option.